# Send data to library project from main project in android

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-library

I am not sure just trying to find out is there any way we can send data from main project to library project ?
Below code giving me **classnotfound** **exception** here **LockScreenActivity** is my library project activity.
I am calling this code from the main project.

```
 Intent myIntent = null;
    try {
        myIntent = new Intent(this,Class.forName("nseit.com.lockscreenusingservice.LockScreenActivity"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myIntent.putExtra("exam_id",exam_id);

    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(myIntent );
```

Comment: have you added a deependancy to your lib project? if yes, then you don't have to find class by name, just import it and use same way as if it was in same project. It you didn't add, then it is not strange that it doesn't find the class.

Comment: I am getting null on the library activity when I am passing data through bundle from the main project.class cast exception is gone but data is null on the library side.
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        try{
            if(intent != null){


                String Examid = intent.getStringExtra("exam_id");

            }

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
Examid is null on the library project..@VladMatvienko

Comment: is `exam_id` a String?

Comment: Yes exam_is is a string

Comment: pls add the error messages from the logcat.